# Lowering Est FG before Brew

Tags: all-grain, final-gravity, saison

I am planning out a Saison and trying to hit the traditional guideline numbers.... I need to get the East Final Gravity down below 1.008 - I am currently way too high. The changes I keep thinking to make aren't changing things how I was hoping and was hoping for advice to get the correct adjustment. Was going to use Wyeast #3724 Belgian Saison. Currently have a 1.061 Est OG and 1.015 Est FG.

Grain Bill is currently:
6 lb. Belgian Pils
2 lb. Belgian Pale
2 lb. Belgian Wheat
1 lb. German Munich
0.5 lb. Smoked Malt

Any tips or advice welcome - thanks!

Comment: How are you planning to mash? Temperature?  I think multi-step mashing could help.

Comment: What if you substitute Vienna for Munich?  It typically has a higher diastatic power.  But personally I would just mash for longer, giving the enzymes more time to work on the starches, resulting in a more fermentable wort, which should be able to ferment lower.  You could also swap out some of the Pils for Belgian Candy sugar, as it's 100% fermentable.

Comment: Have you actually used Wyeast 3724 on this batch, or which yeast have you used?  Wyeast 3724 is known for being very finicky and needs heat applied in order to reach its full potential for attenuation -- think 80 F (27 C).  As indicated in the other comments, we also need to know your mash schedule.

Comment: I agree this yeast is unusual. I used this in a Saison: OG 1.051 FG 1.008. Took 27 days in the fermenter set at 80F. I collected that yeast and used it with a Tripel: OG 1.079 took 35 days to get to 1.014, at 85F. Fermented hard until it hit around 1.030 then slowed down dramatically. Definitely worth the wait, though.

Answer (score 1):

I have consulted the Dutch homebrew forum, and apparently this yeast is indeed finicky, and also ends rather high for a Saison, with an apparent attenuation of 75% to 80%.

At first it will ferment rather well, then it will stall. Keep up the temperature and make sure that you have the possibility to rouse the yeast by swirling the fermenter.

For your mash, try to mash long, more than 60 minutes, at around 64/65° C (good advice in the comments too).

If you don't want to have a problem with FG, then I advise to use Mangrove Jack's M29 French Saison, dry yeast. Never had a problem with, ferments in a couple of days down to 1.000, and also makes a very clear beer.

Answer (score 0):

To adjust the OG, deduct some malt or add some water, of course. But also give your yeast the opportunity to overperform! A couple of pointers on Saison yeasts. First is to add a dose of simple sugar to get the yeast off to a voracious start. The 2nd is to "open ferment", as Drew Beechum sometimes calls it. He suggests putting a piece of foil over the opening instead of the airlock to reduce any pressue buildup. And as others have already said, keep it warm. I use a warming mat and adjust temp by simply moving the carboy further on or off the mat. Search for "drew beechum saison" and you'll find plenty on the subject.
Good luck!